# No USB wifi adapters (3) will show in iwconfig after plugging them in

Tags: networking, 20.04, usb

Ubuntu 20

[Starting with this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1320155/35158) I'm trying to use a USB wifi adapter because I can't get the onboard wifi to detect my (known good working) wifi.  Isolating variables, maybe the onboard wifi doesn't work. This device is way past its warranty. I've always used wired connections with it.

EW-7822UAC: iwconfig shows only wlp3s0 before plugging in. Plugged in device. iwconfig shows only wlp3s0 after plugging in. This one was suggested by someone as a known good working device for Ubuntu 20.

Cudy WU1300S: iwconfig shows only wlp3s0 before plugging in. Plugged in device. No response from iwconfig. Waited several minutes. Powered computer down (ssh became unresponsive, terminated connection, could not reconnect) and rebooted.

Eduplove (no model, says it's compatible with linux): same result as the Cudy WU1300S

Is there some issue with Ubuntu 20 and USB wifi adapters? How do I find it and fix it?

[Use USB wifi instead of internal - manage](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1080173/use-usb-wifi-instead-of-internal-manage) : answer uses deprecated solution

[Unable to see USB wifi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1205360/unable-to-see-usb-wifi) : tried it, instructions are slightly wrong (the script is install.sh) but there was no change

Comment: May we work on this at your other question?

Comment: sure, but I'll leave this up in case someone feels like chiming in -- it seems like it could be 2 different issues

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 20 what version are you using?

Comment: David you put this comment on 2 of my questions -- did you consider you might be wrong? https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/20.04 -- if you're asking for the exact version, why? is it important? It's just a strange comment if you are trying to get the full version number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't really explain why but the issue was:

1. I had an internal wifi card on this machine
2. the antennas for that card were not plugged in

Never had to care about that because I never used the wifi. Must have unplugged them by accident in the past. For some reason when I plugged them in I was suddenly able to use USB wifi.